# Gravity Form Stripe trial + setup fee

Tags: stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to build a subscription plan with free 30day period and a setup fee.
I'm using wordpress with Gravity Form and the Stripe add-on.
In the Stripe form settings the trial can be defined but If I enable the trial period I can't define the setup fee (there's a js hiding the input).
If I setup both of them (forcing the visibility of the field) and try out the form, I get the currency mismatching error (you cannot combine currencies on a single customer stripe). Removing the setup fee fix the error.

How can I solve? Anyone can give me some hint?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing these problem: the solution is using the gform_stripe_customer_after_create hook:

https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_stripe_customer_after_create/#1-create-invoice-item

Have a nice day :)